# why i am getting - file cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system

Tags: python, error-handling, pycharm, virtualenv, sys

While loading a python file in pycharm i am getting the following warning, earlier it was not there also `print('Hello')` is working as expected but i am not able to install django.

```
File C:\Users\abhi\PycharmProjects\django_apps\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see 
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Comment: Did you try reading the URL?

Comment: Note that this error is not about Python, it's about a PowerShell script.

Comment: Yes i have tried the command given there but receiving another error -`'Set-ExecutionPolicy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to check this, it may be helpful.

Here’s how you can make it possible to run the PowerShell script:

> Open the admin level terminal for Windows PowerShell or the IDE you
> are currently using. Enter `Get-ExecutionPolicy`. It shows the policy
> for the current PowerShell session. You can also enter
> `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` to list out the policies for all scopes.
> get-execution-policy Change the execution policy for the scope you
> want.  The command you need for this purpose is: `Set-ExecutionPolic`y
> `-ExecutionPolicy <policy name> -Scope <scope>`.  In general, we
> recommend using `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser`
> `-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`, as it is more secure.  set-execution-policy If it doesn’t solve the issue, enter:
> `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

[Link](https://www.technewstoday.com/cannot-be-loaded-because-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system/)

Comment: `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` This worked for me

Answer (score -1):

I found two ways that you can tackle this problem succesfully:

1. By enabling PowerShell execution policies:

   PS C:\Users\usr1>**Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted**

For example, I encountered this problem when i wanted to run yarn command at my project's root folder. Then by running the command above, I was abled to run the comand yarn without a problem.
[image]

2. Use bash terminal instead of powershell terminal
   You can use this method when you get error from the powershell terminal by running the Set-ExecutionPolicy command. Like the error below:
   [image]
   In such case, by switching your terminal to bash you can have your scripts run:
   [image]